# Vb.net tax calculation display error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am making a tax calculation program , i was having a problem displaying the tax on the mySQl data grid. So i tried this code:

```
If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then

         tax+= sellprice / 18
    End If
End Sub
```

The point is to minus 18% from the sellprice .

Comment: If the tax rate is 18% then the sellprice is 118% of the item price.  If the total is `10` and the tax rate is 18% then the item price was `8.47`.  To check: what is 8.47 x 1.18 ?  Divide the sellprice by `1.18`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it appears you are dividing it by 18.

Maybe you want:

```
tax += sellprice * 0.82
```

or

```
tax += sellprice * 0.18
```

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve, based on your wording.

Comment: If i have a product that is 10 mk denars ( money value) i want to find devide 18% from that price and find what is the 18% tax of 10 denars

Comment: Well then it sounds like you want tax += sellprice * 0.18, as I wrote above.

Comment: the total of the product is 10 mkd denars i want to find what is the 18% tax in 10 denars and write it in the tax field. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: 10 - 18% = 8.2 and i want to display  1.8 in the tax field

Comment: @J.Don: 10 * 0.18 = 1.8.